# Try and catch causing an error with my public void

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

**Before you ask, I have already looked at other questions, they just seem to be for slightly different things.**
I'm new to java and currently learning, so I made this narcissistic program that I'm going to make into a multi-tool sort of thing. That part doesn't really matter.
Basically, I'm making a text input calculator, where you type in numbers and operations and stuff, but it's fairly simple. However, in the input area, I'm trying and catching in case the user types something that isn't a number. But, this makes the variables of x and y (user inputs) to be uninitialized and not readable when initializing the separate *public void calculator(variables)*. This is my code (I've only included the calculator part, the rest is unrelated and all working fine, also I know *x* is differently handled to y, I was testing them both)

```
        public void calculatorvariables() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the first number in your calculation.");
    double x = scanner.nextDouble();
    if(x != (double) x) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred! Did you input nothing or something other than a number? Returning to variable input screen!");
    } else
    System.out.println("Please enter the operator. Valid operators are: '+', '-', '*', '/'");
    String operation = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the second number in your calculation.");
    try {
    double y = scanner.nextDouble();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred! Error message: " + e.getMessage() + " Did you input nothing or something other than a number? Returning to variable input screen!");
    }
    new FirstClass().calculator(x, operation, y);
}
public void calculator(double x, String operation, double y) {
    if(operation.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println(x + y);
    }
    else if(operation.equals("-")) {
        System.out.println(x - y);
    }
    else if(operation.equals("*")) {
        System.out.println(x * y);
    }
    else if(operation.equals("/")) {
        System.out.println(x / y);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Unknown operation! Returning to input area!");
        new FirstClass().calculatorvariables();
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N");
    doAnotherCalculation = scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    if (doAnotherCalculation == true) {
        new FirstClass().calculatorvariables();
    }
    else {
        new FirstClass().mainmenu();
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the variable outside of the try/catch bit, like this:

```
double y;

try {
  y = scanner.nextDouble();
catch (Exception e) {
  // Exception handling
}
```

Comment: That'd be "declaring" the variable. Which is half of the solution. Actually initialising it (I.e. assigning a value) outside of the `try-catch` would help even further.

Comment: Whoops, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSo{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestSo().calculatorvariables();
    } 

    public void calculatorvariables() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number in your calculation.");

        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
        if(x != (double) x) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred! Did you input nothing or something other than a number? Returning to variable input screen!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Please enter the operator. Valid operators are: '+', '-', '*', '/'");
            String operation = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the second number in your calculation.");
            double y = scanner.nextDouble();
            calculator(x, operation, y);
        }
    }

    public void calculator(double x, String operation, double y) {
        if(operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(x + y);
        } else if(operation.equals("-")) {
            System.out.println(x - y);
        } else if(operation.equals("*")) {
            System.out.println(x * y);
        } else if(operation.equals("/")) {
            System.out.println(x / y);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown operation! Returning to input area!");
            calculatorvariables();
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? Y/N");
        boolean doAnotherCalculation = scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
        if (doAnotherCalculation == true) {
            calculatorvariables();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Done! Exiting");
        }

    }
}
```